# Is it better to use the connector filter condition or to filter the record in the handler

Tags: events, event-handling, debezium, connector, change-data-capture

I want to add a new Debezium connector.
Let's say I want to know when the DB field Entity.status changed to "canceled".
What I can do is use groovy like this:

```
"transforms.filter.language": "jsr223.groovy"
```

and then I can add this kind of filer condition:

```
"transforms.filter.condition": "value.before.status != value.after.status && value.after.status == 'canceled'"
```

Another approach would be to send every changed record to my Kafka handler and filter it there:

```
public void onMessage(EntityChangedMessage entityChangedMessage) {
  if(entityChangedMessage.getAfter().getStatus() == entityChangedMessage.getBefore().getStatus() ||
     entityChangedMessage.getAfter().getStatus() != "canceled") {
   return;
  }
  // my logic for when I meet the condition I care for...
}
```

The second approach would let me (or any other developer who cares for it) use this
event for other flows and purposes, even ones that are not related to the status field.
On the other hand, the second approach is a bit messier.
I'd be glad to hear opinions on which approach is better.

Answer (score 1):

TL.DR The common pattern in a CDC environment is to publish all messages and then filter at destination.

Details :

As you have already mentioned , this is opinion based. Here is one such thing you may want to consider

CDC and change capture is widely used for Auditing purposes from a system of record. This enables traceability and track changes in state in the lifecycle of a record (could be anything such as creation of a new account whose state changes from new , pending , approved and cancelled for example)

In most such scenarios , you want all of these state changes. There could be a subset of applications that may want only a specific message for example "cancelled" accounts only , In that scenario may be they filter out the rest of the messages.

What is the downside of this , let us say we get an average of 100k new accounts and say only 100 cancellations , this would mean that the vast majority of messages will need discarding. There could be applications who cannot scale (may be old apps that were not built for so much volume for example). Again , there are ways to solve this by using a scalable router that routes cancelled messages to a specific topic from where it can be consumed.